# Перевод сайта на другие языки PHP

Tags: php

Интересует вопрос, какой метод перевода самый лучший по функциональности, скорости, простоте? Но главное чтобы использовались собственные скрипты, без сторонних плагинов или ресурсов.
Мои варианты:
1. Через файл. ( .txt )
2. Базу данных.
3. Сохранять все слова в массиве PHP.

Видел вариант, в зависимости от страны, php код открывает тот или иной файл .txt, где собственно 2 столбца, слева русские слова а справа перевод на определенный язык.
Если этот способ самый лучший, то был бы признателен помощи в написании скрипта или ссылками на нужную информацию. 
Спасибо.

Comment: по мне, лучше храните переводы в php массиве, типа как en.php, ru.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такое решение.

```
   //вырезаем первые две буквы
   $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

   //Выводим значение языковой константы
   $array =  parse_ini_file('leng/'.$lang.'.ini');
   echo $array["hello"];
```

В самом файле ru.ini сохраняю перевод в виде:
hello=привет

Comment: При каждом запросе парсить один и тот же ini файл - это очень и очень грустно.

Comment: Ну можно сохранить в сессии, если такое возможно. Но по другому я хз.

Comment: Сессии не предназначены для хранения существенных объемов данных.

Comment: Тогда проще грузить файл.

Comment: Проще взять и посмотреть, как это делают взрослые. Например, как устроена система локализации в Symfony.

Comment: Ну как бы я уже всунул такой вариант, и он мне нравиться. Нет не каких лагов.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
// Устанавливаем русский язык
putenv('LC_ALL=ru_RU');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');

// Указываем путь к таблицам переводов
bindtextdomain("myPHPApp", "./locale");

// Выбираем домен
textdomain("myPHPApp");

// Теперь поиск переводов будет идти в ./locale/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/myPHPApp.mo

// Выводим тестовое сообщение
echo gettext("Welcome to My PHP Application");

// Или с использованием псевдонима _()
echo _("Have a nice day");
?>
```

Более подробно тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gettext.php

Answer (score 2):

"без сторонних плагинов или ресурсов." очень трудная задачка. Что могу предложить из самых быстрых методов, создать нейкий класс языков и с помощью его функций получать определенный текст(а в самом классе править язык). "Видел вариант, в зависимости от страны" достаточно распарсить заголовок(`$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]`, как пример `http://tradebenefit.ru/kak-opredelit-jazyk-polzovatelja-v-php`) и достать из него язык(выбор языка тоже кстати).

Можно попробовать способ и полегче воспользоваться гугл переводчиком `https://translate.google.com/manager/website/` (часто встречаю его на англ сайтах).

Comment: Полезная штука. Но это лишь определение предпочитаемого языка пользователя. Мне все же больше нужно сам принцип перевода, то есть вывод к примеру определенный .txt файл и вставку слов на странице сайта. Или лучше через базу данных?